# volume calculator with multiple measurement options

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create a volume calculator in which the users can enter the width length and depth, as well as a choice of 5 different units. they can have all three in different units if they so wished but i need the output to be in metres^3.

so i thought the easiest way would be to convert all measurements to metres first and then just multiply them all to get the volume, however being a rookie to javascript and coding in general im finding this to be a big challenge than I thought.

below is my HTML and JS code

I tried my best to show my thinking (through the use of comments) and what i was trying to achieve at each stage of the js code.

the below code doesn't output anything and im not sure where ive gone wrong or even if any of it is even right! Any help in appreciated however I would greatly appriacte comments explaining where i went wrong hints what i should focus on for next time as well as any reading recommended etc as i am trying to improve rather than just get the solution and gain no additional knowledge :)

Thank you again!

```js
Function calculateVolume() {
  //get width inputted by user and assigns it to width
  var width =
    document.getElementById("width")
  // get width measurement selected by user and assigns it to widthMeasurement
  var widthMeasurement =
    document.getElementById("width-type")
  // checks to see which measurement is selected and converts it into metres 
  if ("widthMeasurement" = "Centimeters") {
    var widthInMetres =
      width * 100
  } else if ("widthMeasurement" = "inches") {
    var widthInMetres =
      width * 39.37
  } else if ("widthMeasurement" = "feet") {
    var widthInMetres =
      width * 3.28084
  } else if ("widthMeasurement" = "yards") {
    var widthInMetres =
      width * 1.09361
  } else if ("widthMeasurement" = "metres") {
    var widthInMetres = width
  }

  //repeated process for length


  //get length inputted by user and assigns it to length
  var length =
    document.getElementById("length")
  // get length measurement selected by user and assigns it to lengthMeasurement
  var lengthMeasurement =
    document.getElementById("length-type")
  // checks to see which measurement is selected and converts it into metres 
  if ("lengthMeasurement" = "Centimeters") {
    var lengthInMetres =
      length * 100
  } else if ("lengthMeasurement" = "inches") {
    var lengthInMetres =
      length * 39.37
  } else if ("lengthMeasurement" = "feet") {
    var lengthInMetres =
      length * 3.28084
  } else if ("lengthMeasurement" = "yards") {
    var lengthInMetres =
      lengt * 1.09361
  } else if ("lengthMeasurement" = "metres") {
    var lengthInMetres = length
  }



  //get depth inputted by user and assigns it to depth
  var depth =
    document.getElementById("depth")
  // get depth measurement selected by user and assigns it to depthMeasurement
  var depthMeasurement =
    document.getElementById("depth-type")
  // checks to see which measurement is selected and converts it into metres 
  if ("depthMeasurement" = "Centimeters") {
    var depthInMetres =
      depth * 100
  } else if ("depthMeasurement" = "inches") {
    var depthInMetres =
      depth * 39.37
  } else if ("depthMeasurement" = "feet") {
    var depthInMetres =
      depth * 3.28084
  } else if ("depthMeasurement" = "yards") {
    var depthInMetres =
      depth * 1.09361
  } else if ("depthMeasurement" = "metres") {
    var dephInMetres = depth
  }

  var totalvolume = lengthInMetres * widthInMetres * dephInMetres;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = totalvolume;
}
```

```html
<table class="calculator">
  <div class="calculatorheading">
    <h1> Use our simple calculator below to calculate the amount you need!</h1>
  </div>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Width</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="width" /></td>
      <td>
        <select id="width-type">
          <option value="meters">Metres</option>
          <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
          <option value="inches">Inches</option>
          <option value="feet">Feet</option>
          <option value="yards">Yards</option>

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Length</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="length" /></td>
      <td>
        <select id="length-type">
          <option value="meters">Metres</option>
          <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
          <option value="inches">Inches</option>
          <option value="feet">Feet</option>
          <option value="yards">Yards</option>

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Depth</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="depth" /></td>
      <td>
        <select id="depth-type">
          <option value="meters">Metres</option>
          <option value="centimeter">Centimeter</option>
          <option value="inches">Inches</option>
          <option value="feet">Feet</option>
          <option value="yards">Yards</option>

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <button onclick="calculateVolume()">Calculate</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `Function` should be `function`, JS is case sensitive.

Comment: You several problems. You have quotes around your variable names. You didn't use `.value` to get the value of the input.

Comment: `if ("widthMeasurement" = "Centimeters")` does not make any sense. If anything you want to use the variable `widthMeasurement` (no quotes) and also a comparison `===` instead of assignment. Though for a `select` element you should check the `selectedIndex` instead of making string comparisons

Comment: Instead of repeating all those `if` statements, you should define a function that does the conversion, or use an object that maps units to the multiplier.

Comment: You need to learn the basics. I suggest you try a simpler project first, then work your way up to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `<div>` is not a valid immediate `<table>` descendant
- Create an object with your units *to-Meter* values multipliers  (reusability in mind). `toMeters` in the example below.
- Remember that input values (even if `type="number"`) are **always a String** - therefore in JavaScript you'll have to parse that String to Float using `parseFloat(str)`
- Use `.toFixed()` to round precision to a defined decimals points precision

```js
// Just some nifty helpers to get DOM element/s
const ELS = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);

// Cache your elements
const EL_result = EL("#result");
const EL_w  = EL("#width");
const EL_l  = EL("#length");
const EL_d  = EL("#depth");
const EL_uw = EL("#unit-width");
const EL_ul = EL("#unit-length");
const EL_ud = EL("#unit-depth");

const toMeters = (str = "1", unit = "m") => str.trim() * {
  m : 1,
  cm: 100,
  in: 39.37,
  ft: 3.28084,
  yd: 1.09361
}[unit];

function calcVol() {
  const w = toMeters(EL_w.value, EL_uw.value);
  const l = toMeters(EL_l.value, EL_ul.value);
  const d = toMeters(EL_d.value, EL_ud.value);
  const tot = w * l * d;
  EL_result.textContent = Number(tot.toFixed(5));
}

ELS(".calc").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("input", calcVol));
// init!
calcVol();
```

```css
span.label {display: inline-block; min-width: 80px; font:14px sans-serif;}
```

```html
<span class="label">Width</span>
<input id="width" class="calc" type="number" value="1" min="0" step="0.1">
<select id="unit-width" class="calc">
  <option value="m">Metres</option>
  <option value="cm">Centimeter</option>
  <option value="in">Inches</option>
  <option value="ft">Feet</option>
  <option value="yd">Yards</option>
</select>
<br>
<span class="label">Length</span>
<input id="length" class="calc" type="number" value="1" min="0" step="0.1">
<select id="unit-length" class="calc">
  <option value="m">Metres</option>
  <option value="cm">Centimeter</option>
  <option value="in">Inches</option>
  <option value="ft">Feet</option>
  <option value="yd">Yards</option>
</select>
<br>
<span class="label">Depth</span>
<input id="depth" class="calc" type="number" value="1" min="0" step="0.1">
<select id="unit-depth" class="calc">
  <option value="m">Metres</option>
  <option value="cm">Centimeter</option>
  <option value="in">Inches</option>
  <option value="ft">Feet</option>
  <option value="yd">Yards</option>
</select>
<br>
<span class="label">VOLUME:</span>
<span id="result">0</span> m<sup>3</sup>
```